# bloom-release fais: Aborting pull request: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized

Tags: ros, bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been seeing this for a few years IIRC and finally feeling like resolving.

`bloom-release` seems to be working fine except that it fails to open a PR on rosdistro github repo.

```
$ bloom-release --rosdistro melodic --track melodic scan_tools --edit
:
==> Checking on GitHub for a fork to make the pull request from...
Could not find a fork of ros/rosdistro on the 130s GitHub account.
Would you like to create one now?
Continue [Y/n]? 
Aborting pull request: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized (https://api.github.com/repos/ros/rosdistro/forks)
The release of your packages was successful, but the pull request failed.
Please manually open a pull request by editing the file here: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/melodic/distribution.yaml'
<== No pull request opened.
```

No idea what's wrong, nor what to look (other than looking into bloom's code, which I don't mind doing)

```
$ apt-cache policy python3-bloom
python3-bloom:
  Installed: 0.10.1-100
  Candidate: 0.10.1-100
  Version table:
 *** 0.10.1-100 500
        500 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
```

Part of my git config:

```
$ more ~/.gitconfig 
[core]
        editor = emacs -nw
[credential]
        helper = cache --timeout=14400
# Enforce SSH
##[url "ssh://git@github.com/"]
##  insteadOf = https://github.com/
# Always use ssh for github, even if the remote URL uses https or git
[url "git@github.com:"]
        insteadOf = git://github.com/
[url "git@github.com:"]
        insteadOf = https://github.com/
[fetch]
        prune = true
[url "git@gitlab.com:"]
        insteadOf = https://gitlab.com/
```

Another example ([ros-drivers/rgbd_launch#48](https://github.com/ros-drivers/rgbd_launch/issues/48#issuecomment-637884114))

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/371864/bloom-release-fais:-aborting-pull-request:-http-error-401:-unauthorized/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2021-02-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-15**:
Is this [ros-infrastructure/bloom#611](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom/issues/611) (or any of the others like it: [ros-infrastructure/bloom#605](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom/issues/605) or [ros-infrastructure/bloom#590](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom/issues/590))?

**Comment by [clalancette](https://answers.ros.org/users/30031/clalancette/) on 2021-02-23**:
Do you have 2-factor authentication enabled on your account?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2021-02-24**:
Yes > MFA,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For MFA, you have to setup bloom with an oauth token: http://wiki.ros.org/bloom/Tutorials/GithubManualAuthorization .  In short, besides the URL rewrites, you also need to add a file `~/.config/bloom` that contains something like:

`{"github_user": <your-user>, "oauth_token": <your-token>}`

---

Originally posted by [clalancette](https://answers.ros.org/users/30031/clalancette/) with karma: 256 on 2021-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3